# Local notification in Cordova using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, cordova-plugins

Hi I'm developing an app with Cordova and i can not find a solution to this problem.
Every two hours i should query the database by sending a data from the application and receive a list from the database by sending a notifier if there are some conditions.
I've tried with local notifications, but it works perfectly only when the app is open.
Can I run ajax functions when the app is closed?

Comment: No, you can't.  You have to use push notifications.  That's the whole point of push notifications, to push data to your app when it's not open.

Comment: Thanks, but can you send data from the application and receive a response?

Comment: Nope, when your app isn't running, it's... not running.  The best you can do is register each app installation with your backend and have the backend push a notification to the appropriate installation as needed.